# Nested condition in pandas caused ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 20], ['A', 2, 30], ['B', 1, 50], ['B', 3, 45], ['A', 4, 60], ['B', 5, 70]])
df.columns = ['Type', 'P', 'X']
```

df:

```
  Type  P   X
0    A  1  20

1    A  2  30

2    B  1  50

3    B  3  45

4    A  4  60

5    B  5  70
```

Expectation:

I want to apply nested conditions to calculate a value and append it as a new column.

This is what I did:

```
result = 0
if (df.Type == 'A'):
    if df.P % 2 == 0:
        result = df.X+10
    else:
        restult = df.X+20
else:
    if df.P % 2 == 0:
        result = df.X+30
    else:
        result = df.X+40
df['Result'] = result
```

The expected output is:

```
 Type  P   X   Result

0    A  1  20   40

1    A  2  30   40

2    B  1  50   90

3    B  3  45   85

4    A  4  60   70

5    B  5  70   110
```

But it failed with error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I've dug other threads but they seem to be other issues.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.select(listof conditions, listofchoices, alternative)`

```
condition=[(df.Type == 'A')&(df.P % 2 != 0),(df.Type == 'A')&(df.P % 2 == 0), (df.Type == 'B')&(df.P % 2 == 0)]
    
choices= [df.X+20,df.X+10,df.X+30]

df['result'] = np.select(condition, choices,df.X+40)

    Type  P   X  result
0    A  1  20      40
1    A  2  30      40
2    B  1  50      90
3    B  3  45      85
4    A  4  60      70
5    B  5  70     110
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this way, if df.Type == 'B', then this return is False, and then the whole return is always False no matter df.P is odd or even. So far there is no meaning for considering the 'and' condition of whether df.P is odd or even. Am I right? And if I want to use the conditional statements, what should I correct?

Comment: What result did you expect in B, I didnt see B in your condition so didnt know how to factor. Can you give a brief explanation?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've changed some details to clarify some confusion, and also add the expected output. Could you double check it, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`if` operator is not vectorized and can't be used with Series, use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead:

```
type_a, p_even = df.Type == 'A', df.P % 2 == 0
amount = np.select(
    [type_a & p_even, type_a & ~p_even, ~type_a & p_even, ~type_a & ~p_even], 
    [10, 20, 30, 40]
)
df['Result'] = df.X + amount

df
  Type  P   X  Result
0    A  1  20      40
1    A  2  30      40
2    B  1  50      90
3    B  3  45      85
4    A  4  60      70
5    B  5  70     110
```